# Application Client Server Java EE ( Java Enterprise Edition)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, client-server, vaadin

I've to implement an application for sending messages.

The Application should support different type of messages.

Plus the application should offer simple UI with some characteristics like Input for messages to a contact (STRING (email for example)), Input for message text, Selection for message type, send button, list of messages that have been already sent, list should contain message type, recipient and content

After pressing send button the message is shown in the list of messages

Application should be implemented in Client – Server architecture with using Java EE.

The Client has to be a standalone application.

EJB should be used for remote invocations. 
Methods for message sending and obtaining list of sent messages should offered.

plus:
Extendable design (idea: more message types are coming soon)
Sent messages are persisted on server side and available when application is opened again (file can be used to store messages).

Preferred UI choice: Vaadin.

Is not necessary to implement the actual sending. it is enough to write into logs/system out that sms or email was sent along with recipient and message content (in addition to storing it in some db/file)

For Server part use JBoss 7.

Now I'm getting crazy over this program because is required something that i don't understand. Vaadin is for web applications. Is out there anyone that can help me to understand how to proceed about creating a UI using Vaadin for a standalone client that comunicates with the server side?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All your UI requirements can be implemented using standard server-side components of vaadin framework, there is no need to use client-side widgets. 
If you still need to use the client-side components - read a chapter of vaadin book devoted to architecture:

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/architecture.html#architecture.overview

and a part of the book devoted to the client-side development:

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/part-clientside.html

Comment: I'm creating an Enterprise Application. I did everything  about EJB and about the classes connected to it. So far i was testing what done using a normal servlet that lookingUp to the EJB where able to comunicate.My problem is that i'm trying now to apply a UI to my servlet. I don't know if that is possible. so I created the Vaadin project with deployment as servlet. then i add another servlet that lookup to the EJB. I tried but once added in the Enterprise Project in order to deploy is not possible to accede to the servlet not even directly bypassing the ClassUI from the localhost.